# UWP SQLite CodenameOne with native interface

Tags: codenameone

I see that Codename One does not support SQLite database on UWP. 
Does this functionality will be added later as SQLite is now included in the UWP SDK ? 
In order to bypass this limitation, is it possible to had a native interface ? Documentation talks about IOS and Android but UWP...
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UWP port is slowly maturing in beta so things like sqlite aren't implemented yet. I've filed an RFE and set it for 3.7 which is scheduled for early 2017: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1889

This might be implemented sooner but it is hard to tell...

Normally we schedule tasks based on requests from enterprise customers and we are currently bogged down with tasks. In fact one of the things we need to do for the UWP port (which we will probably do sooner) is implement native interfaces properly.

Assuming native interfaces will get implemented soon (which should be the case), doing this in a native interface will be VERY challenging!

Database access is complex and would require a large/elaborate porting layer.

If you are really serious about doing this yourself the best way is to do it thru a pull request. You can just fork our git project http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/ and hack the SQL support into the UWP port. If you get something working you can contribute it back via a pull request and it will get incorporated.

Other possible strategies moving forward would be:

- Try to use other storage options such as `Storage` for your data. Those are far more portable
- Try to port a lightweight database such as HSql to Codename One. This would require some work but might be rewarding
- Wait for us to do that or optionally sign up as an enterprise developer and make us do it sooner

Comment: Many thanks for updating UWP port with SQLite. I successfully build demo sample. I will now start my project. I'm sure, that this functionality will attract new developers, so you may update the JavaDoc of "Database" very quickly. Your project is amazing so good luck to you !